# combinding Struct + malloc in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am trying to make a malloc based on a struct.

The struct looks like this:

```
    struct shirts
        {
        char color[10];
        int size;
        };

struct shirts* ptr_shirts;
```

I then want to make x amount of t-shirts so i have a variable for that:

```
printf("How many T-shirts? ");
            scanf("%d",&amount);
            getchar();
            ptr_shirts = (struct shirts *)malloc(amount * sizeof(struct shirts));
```

I then want to fille the spaces but i dont know how to do it. I have tried to use a for loop and put in values like it is an array:

```
for(i = 0; i<amount;i++)
            {
            printf("Color on T-shirt nr %d: ",(i+1));
            scanf_s("%s", "what to type here" ,sizeof(ptr_shirts->color));
            printf("Size on T-shirt nr %d: ",(i+1));
            scanf("%d",&"what to type here");
            }
```

i have tried with

```
ptr_shirts[i].size
ptr_shirts->size[i]
(ptr_shirts.size 
and then ptr_shirts++)
```

but i dont know how to make it easy becuase i want to fill more then 1 t-shirt, thats the problem i got

Comment: You can use the pointer using array-indexing syntax, so `ptr_shirts[i].size` is correct, for values of `i` in the range 0 <= i < amount.

Comment: Observe that you have to pass the pointer to the `size` member, so you have to dereference with the ampersand (`&`). But in case of the `color` member, the `char` array will decay to a pointer to the first cell on its own.

Comment: Oh and by the way, [in C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `color` array member note that `scanf_s` function is non-standard (well, to be honest in except to C11 with (optional though) Annex B, but it's not well-adopted yet), you might use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) along with `stdin` as an "safer" alternative.

In case of `size` member it should be just:

```
&ptr_shirts[i].size
```

(that is: `scanf("%d", &ptr_shirts[i].size);`)

or alternatively:

```
&(ptr_shirts + i)->size
```

Couple of additional notes:

- [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- always check returned value from `malloc()`, as it might be `NULL`

Answer (score -1):

```
Try This -
ptr_shirts = (struct shirts *)malloc(amount * sizeof(struct shirts));

for(i = 0; i<amount;i++)
        {
           memset (ptr_shirts[i],0,sizeof(struct shirts)); /*Assign structure variable to NULL*/
           printf("Color on T-shirt nr %d: ",(i+1));
           scanf_s("what to type here %s", ptr_shirts[i].color,_countof(ptr_shirts[i].color));
           printf("Size on T-shirt nr %d: ",(i+1));
           scanf_s("what to type here %d", ptr_shirts[i].size,_countof(ptr_shirts[i].size));
        }
```